# How to determine whether a path is containing a format at the end?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some URLs like these:

```
http://example.com/class/method/arg1
http://example.com/class/method/image.jpg
http://example.com/class/method/arg1.png
http://example.com/class/method/arg1/arg2/
http://example.com/class/method/arg1.gif/
```

I want output in order:

```
false
true
true
false
true
```

So, as you see in examples above, I'm trying to detect a path is a image or not .. How can I do that?

---

This regex checks just four last characters for `.jpg`:

```
^.*([^.]...|.[^j]..|..[^p].|...[^g])$
```

I can write multiple regex like that for all cases (`.png`, `.gif`, ...), But I want to know, is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for strings that end in `.jpg`, `.gif` or `.png` then you need

```
\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$
```

Comment: Good answer, if you are trying to match case, don't bother. File names are not case sensitive. Just convert to lower case before the .match command.

Comment: @magreenberg: The syntax for case-insensitivity depends on the language, so I wrote a solution without. In Perl it would have a `/i`

Comment: With a little modification like this `\.(?:jpg|gif|png)\/?$` it will also match the last case `http://example.com/class/method/arg1.gif/`

Comment: @noob: If the OP has something like `http://example.com/class/method/arg1.gif/` then something is *seriously* wrong with the server. And you shouldn't escape slashes unless your forced to

Comment: @Borodin We don't always look out for code that deals with servers that are under our control - the OP (and me) could be building a scraper or a browser extension for same purposes. A little more info never hurts.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides:Then you should have checked the URL *way* earlier

Answer (score 1):

Then you simply enforce the allowed last 4 chars like this: `/\.jpg$/`

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/wB0oI2/1)

To allow more including and optional last slash: `/\.(jpg|gif|png|XYZ)\/?$/`

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/wB0oI2/2)

Comment: I think you should read the question. Regex questions have become the go-to topic for easy points, and also for dreadful answers. Please don't reply unless you have a solid solution

Comment: And please don't copy other people's solutions into your own